# Datagridview - decimal Positions in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

In my Grid it is showing all decimal positions which is coming from textfile.

For example : **Weight** column in Grid has : `1.000`

But when I try to get the value from `DataGridView` it is showing only one(1) not with decimal positions.

```
Value = DgdOrderInfo.Rows(Intcnt).Cells("Weight").Value.ToString.Trim
```

Let me know how can I get all digits values ?

Comment: Weird, I assumed when I answered the question that you were working in C# because the code snippet looked like C#. Then I noticed the VB.NET tag...

Answer (score 0):

Each cell in a DataGridView can have a [`DataGridViewCellStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.aspx) applied to it, which contains (among other things) a [`Format` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.format.aspx) that governs how the contents of that cell should be displayed. And an entire column or row can be assigned a default cell style that it uses for all of the cells in that row.

So probably what is happening is that you have a formatting string in use for your "Weight" column that formats all values with three trailing decimal places. When you retrieve the value, it is actually *is* just `1`, but it is being displayed as `1.000` because of the formatting rules applied to all cells in that column.

If you want to retrieve this formatted value, you can do so by accessing the [`FormattedValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.formattedvalue) property, rather than the `Value` property. The necessary changes to your code are simple:

```
string value = DgdOrderInfo.Rows(Intcnt).Cells("Weight").FormattedValue.ToString.Trim
```

I also doubt very seriously that there is any need to call the `Trim` method on the return string.

Comment: thanks for your help, in grid Weight  has different decimal format. in first it has 0 decimal. in 2 row it has 2 decimal.like : 2.15. it is showing correctly. but when decimal position is zero only it it not showing.

Comment: Right, because 0s aren't actually there. They are meaningless. `1.000` is exactly the same as `1`. That's not the case with `2.15`, that's a very different value from `2`. The difference in output is all controlled by formatting rules.

Comment: Thanks, is there any chance to get all values.

Comment: `FormattedValue` didn't work I suppose? No idea then, you'll need to post more code.